# Is it possible to Alpha Blend a VCL control on a TForm?

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to Alpha Blend or implement a similar effect for a VCL control on a TForm?

For example, consider the following screenshot where two TPanels are placed on a TForm in addition to other controls. Both the panels are made draggable (*See* [How to Move and Resize Controls at Run Time](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa102505a.htm)).

Now, is it possible to make these panels translucent while dragging so that you can see what is underneath? *(as shown in the second image which was produced by image manipulation)*

[image: Sample form image]

[image: Solution proposed by TLama and Uwe Raabe]

Comment: Not in any simple way, I am afraid. (BTW: *Never* use JPG for screenshots, unless they chiefly contain photographic images! Use PNG instead-)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: Is it possible to do it in any language other than Delphi? There must be some way to do it because in Firefox if you drag the above image around the screen you can still see what is behind it.

Another place you can see a similar effect is on Windows 7 taskbar.

Comment: What you see e.g. in Firefox as you mentioned is the image of OLE drag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in Delphi, too. The basic idea is to place the control into an autosized, borderles form with alpha blending enabled.

According to the article you linked to, in the MouseDown event add the following lines:

```
  P := TWinControl(Sender).ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));
  frm := TForm.Create(nil);
  TWinControl(Sender).Parent := frm;
  frm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  frm.AlphaBlend := true;
  frm.AlphaBlendValue := 128;
  frm.AutoSize := true;
  frm.Left := P.X;
  frm.Top := P.Y;
  frm.Position := poDesigned;
  frm.Show;
```

In the MouseMove event set the Left and Top properties of the controls parent:

```
  GetCursorPos(newPos);

  Screen.Cursor := crSize;
  Parent.Left := Parent.Left - oldPos.X + newPos.X;
  Parent.Top := Parent.Top - oldPos.Y + newPos.Y;
  oldPos := newPos;
```

and in the MouseUp event release the form, set the controls parent back to the original parent and translate the screen position to the new position relative to it:

```
frm := TWinControl(Sender).Parent;
P := Point(frm.Left, frm.Top);
P := ScreenToClient(P);
TWinControl(Sender).Parent := Self;
TWinControl(Sender).Left := P.X;
TWinControl(Sender).Top := P.Y;
frm.Free;
Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
ReleaseCapture;
inReposition := False;
```

Comment: Close enough, but the form is stealing the focus.

Comment: That works for most part! That is lateral thinking!! Only problem I can see now is that it steals the focus away from the original form.

Comment: @TLama, What about a SetFocus after the frm.Show?

Comment: @Uwe, might work, but I would prefer `ShowWindow(frm.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE); frm.Visible := True;`. And rather use `Release` instead of `Free`. I know, that there's no risk here, but some people may refer to it as a correct way to free the form.

Comment: This solution with ShowWindow(frm.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE); frm.Visible := True; works exactly as I envisioned! Thank you TLama and Uwe Raabe!!

Answer (score 17):

The VCL gives you the opportunity to [specify a drag image list](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorCon2001/DragAndDrop/4114.htm#VCLDragImages) to be used during drag-and-drop, here's a quick example:
[image]

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TPanel = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  protected
    function GetDragImages: TDragImageList; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
    procedure PanelStartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
    procedure PanelEndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    FDragImages: TDragImageList;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TPanel }

function TPanel.GetDragImages: TDragImageList;
begin
  Result := (Owner as TForm1).FDragImages;
end;

type
  TControlProc = reference to procedure(Control: TControl);

procedure IterateControls(Control: TControl; Proc: TControlProc);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(Control) then
    Proc(Control);
  if Control is TWinControl then
    for I := 0 to TWinControl(Control).ControlCount - 1 do
      IterateControls(TWinControl(Control).Controls[I], Proc);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDragImages := nil;
  // set display drag image style
  IterateControls(Self,
    procedure(Control: TControl)
    begin
      Control.ControlStyle := Control.ControlStyle + [csDisplayDragImage];
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := Source is TPanel;
end;

procedure TForm1.PanelEndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FDragImages);
end;

procedure TForm1.PanelStartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
var
  Image: TBitmap;
begin
  if not (Sender is TPanel) then
    Exit;

  Image := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Image.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Image.Width := TControl(Sender).Width;
    Image.Height := TControl(Sender).Height;
    TPanel(Sender).PaintTo(Image.Canvas, 0, 0);

    FDragImages := TDragImageList.Create(nil);
    FDragImages.Width := Image.Width;
    FDragImages.Height := Image.Height;
    FDragImages.SetDragImage(FDragImages.Add(Image, nil), 0, 0);
    FDragImages.ShowDragImage;
  except
    Image.Free;
    FreeAndNil(FDragImages);
    raise;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: +1 for the interposer class and override the GetDragImages method.

Comment: Your solution is very elegant and it looks like this is the natural way to do the task. Even though I said Firefox as the example, I really want the panel to move away from its current position when it is moved (not just its image). It may be able to produce the same effect by hiding the source panel, I guess. I am looking for a feature more like Windows 7 task bar (where you can re-arrange application icons by drag/drop).

Answer (score 6):

To implement a drag operation displaying the image of the control, you must create a [`TDragControlObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TDragControlObject) descendent and implement the [`GetDragImages`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TDragControlObject.GetDragImages) method, from here you must ensure to add the *csDisplayDragImage* value to the [ControlStyle](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ControlStyle) property of the controls to drag.

You can find a very good article about this topic here [`Implementing Professional Drag & Drop In VCL/CLX Applications`](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorCon2001/DragAndDrop/4114.htm#VCLHotSpots)

Comment: It took me too long to find out how to grab the screenshot of my app running in a Windows VM on a Mac. ;-)

Comment: I was just writing Delphi a sample like yours but using a TDragControlObject, but then I saw your answer :), Anyway i like your idea of use a interposer class and override the GetDragImages method.

Comment: Thanks for the link "Implementing Professional Drag & Drop In VCL/CLX Applications"