# How to have text as my drag cursor?

Tags: delphi

When drag / dropping text between two components, is there a simple way to show the text that I am dragging as the drag cursor?

Comment: Surely you mean *in addition to* the drag cursor? I mean, how would you tell where the 'text-cursor' hotpoint is?

Comment: +1 Good point - unless the hotpoint was top left of the text

Comment: make a separate AlwaysOnTop transparent windows with text and move it to always be near or under the cursor. Like Stardock CursorFX does it.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627526/is-it-possible-to-alpha-blend-a-vcl-control-on-a-tform/12629373#12629373) if you mean drag image.

Comment: +1 for a good link. But it doesn't do what I want (unless I can easily make an image of the text)

Comment: Sure you can easily make an image of the text: Image.[Canvas.TextOut](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextOut)

Comment: A mandatory reading: [Implementing Professional Drag & Drop In VCL/CLX Applications](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorCon2001/DragAndDrop/4114.htm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To drag an item from a listbox, and show its text representation along with the drag cursor:

```
type
  TTextDragObject = class(TDragControlObjectEx)
  private
    FDragImages: TDragImageList;
    FText: String;
  protected
    function GetDragImages: TDragImageList; override;
  end;

{ TTextDragObject }

function TTextDragObject.GetDragImages: TDragImageList;
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  if FDragImages = nil then
  begin
    FDragImages := TDragImageList.Create(Control);
    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bmp.Width := Bmp.Canvas.TextWidth(FText);
      Bmp.Height := Bmp.Canvas.TextHeight(FText);
      Bmp.Canvas.TextOut(0, 0, FText);
      FDragImages.Width := Bmp.Width;
      FDragImages.Height := Bmp.Height;
      FDragImages.SetDragImage(FDragImages.Add(Bmp, nil), 0, 0);
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
  Result := FDragImages;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csDisplayDragImage];
  ListBox1.ControlStyle := ListBox1.ControlStyle + [csDisplayDragImage];
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1StartDrag(Sender: TObject;
  var DragObject: TDragObject);
var
  List: TListbox absolute Sender;
begin
  DragObject := TTextDragObject.Create(List);
  if List.ItemIndex > -1 then
    TTextDragObject(DragObject).FText := List.Items[List.ItemIndex];
end;
```

Comment: Ok, it works. +1 and the answer, @NLGN. However, users should beware that if their OnDragDop handler checks the source component, it is going to be of type TTextDragObject. No problem for me, since I only have one source and one destination, but ...  Also, I put a few spaces bfore the text, to get it our from under the cursor.

Comment: @Mawg - Use `DragHotspot` of TTextDragObject instead of offsetting the image.

Comment: @Mawg `TTextDragObject(Source).Control` is the source component.